# issue when using SMTP and javax.mail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using the following in my sbt build file (versions are mentioned in the build file):

```
  "javax.mail" % "javax.mail-api" % "1.5.5",
  "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4.7",
```

I can run the application that runs the following code on one computer but not another.  I have tried clearing up the ivy cache and reloading the javax mail packages but that has not helped.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
final Transport transport = session.getTransport(prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.protocol"));
transport.connect(prop.getProperty("smtp.username"), "");
```

The properties being used are not null and are being used locally on one computer (and also by another process on the same computer where I am running into issues - that process is no longer running on that computer and should not have an open transport connection).

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;)V
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:2014)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1936)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:192)
```

**com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport  v1.4.7**

```
private void More ...initStreams() throws IOException {
2011    boolean quote = PropUtil.getBooleanSessionProperty(session,
2012                    "mail.debug.quote", false);
2013
2014    traceInput =
2015        new TraceInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream(), traceLogger);
```

Any thoughts on how I should go about troubleshooting this?  I have tried running the session in debug:

```
session.setDebug(true);
```

I do not think its a firewall issue because I can run another process using the same SMTP config (host/port/credentials) and that is able to connect without any exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by transitive dependency in the build file (whereby another dependency was pulling an older version of javax.mail for the application).  Excluding the transitive dependency (using the exclusion rule in sbt) should resolve the issue.

Comment: Note that you've got two versions of JavaMail specified in your dependencies.  You probably want only the com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.5 artifact.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to a missing `smtp.jar` on your classpath.

You can download it as part of the JavaMail API [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)

Comment: the smtp code is in a common package which is being used by different applications.  One sends the email and another does not.  I am running one with the java -jar command (created the jar) while the second is being run from sbt.  I can run the same processes using sbt on a different computer and it works fine there.

Comment: Then you should check if your jar has ´smtp.jar´ in classpath

Comment: thank you - the issue was due to a transitive dependency adding another version of java mail in the build